# Moving fullscreen background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

Have been looking for two days now but after all the Googling still no idea how to achieve what I want.

Hope anyone can help me.

I want my background image to move like this: http://www.theophile-patachou.com/nl/

Any suggestions? Dug through stackoverflow like I was searching gold but no result...

Guess the way to go is css transform?

I tried to use these examples to build it but the outcome was really not as desired http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/

Comment: try searching for Fullscreen Background Image Slideshow

Comment: This may help you: https://css-tricks.com/auto-moving-parallax-background/

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with css @keyframes

```
@keyframes background-animation {
    0%   { background-size:100% auto; }
    50% { background-size:150% auto; }
    100% { background-size:100% auto; }
}

#divwiththebackground {
  animation:background-animation 10s infinite;
}
```

This would animate the background from 100% the width of the div to 150% the width of the div and back over 10 seconds (this can be made shorter/longer and the animations could be changed, i.e. moving the background as well with background-position)

Comment: It would be better if you explain your answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that zooming affect using jquery animate function (http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$('img').animate({width:'+=300',height:'+=300'},16000);
$('img').animate({width:'-=300',height:'-=300'},16000);
```

if you need use `setInterval` and call repeatedly.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('img').animate({width:'+=300',height:'+=300'},16000);
    $('img').animate({width:'-=300',height:'-=300'},16000);
},32100);
```